# onchange handler with quoted text

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use some inline javascript/jquery in an on change handler of a radio button:

```
<input  
   name="Operator" 
    type="radio" 
    value="@Model.Operator"
    checked="true"
    onChange="@radioOnChange"
/>
```

The test version of radioChange looks like this:

```
@{
    const string radioOnChange =
    "var name = $(this).attr('name');" +
    "alert(name);" +
    "var selector = &quot;span[name='&quot; + name + &quot;']&quot;; "+
            "alert(selector);
}
```

For the "var selector = "span['+name+']"" part I tried a zillion different variations using "\" the html "&" escapes, etc. But right one eludes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the trick was using a McvHtmlString like so:

```
<input  
   name="Operator" 
    type="radio" 
    value="@Model.Operator"
    checked="true"
    onChange="@MvcHtmlString.Create(radioOnChange)"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right one should be: `"var selector = &quot;span[name='" + name + "']&quot;; "`, which will produce: `var selector = "span[name='selectorName']";`

I also recommend using `\"` instead of `&quot;` - I guess it's all the same but more readable (maybe someone should correct me if I'm wrong?)

Comment: @Popov: the \" doesn't work, I tried it.
I'm now using var selector =&quot;span[name='&quot; + name + &quot;']&quot;;" that works, but only when I insert it using onChange="@MvcHtmlString.Create(radioOnChange)".

Thanks for the help